# panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, tcp, docker-compose, go-gorm

I'm trying connect mysql server from docker using golang gin gorm.

The build itself has succeeded, but as shown in the title, the following error has been issued.

```
panic: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused
```

Trying to connect in this way

```
func dbConnect() *gorm.DB {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "docker:password@/godocker")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return db
}
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7.26
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: docker
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: godocker
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

Result of hitting `docker-compose ps` command

```
      Name                   Command             State                 Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gin-docker_api_1   /bin/sh -c gin -i run         Up      0.0.0.0:3001->3001/tcp
gin-docker_db_1    docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

Thanks

Comment: MySQL is not running in the localhost, or at least not listening to TCP port 3306, and neither is anything else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should connect to connect via container's name instead

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.7.26
  container_name: godockerDB
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: docker
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    MYSQL_DATABASE: godocker
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

Then you can conenct via container name

```
func dbConnect() *gorm.DB {
db, err := gorm.Open("mysql", "docker:password@tcp(godockerDB)/godocker")

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

    return db
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!

I fix my issue!!

why use connect via container_name?

Comment: Because docker composer use docker network. That allow you connect via container's name as an network alias https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/